# Cshell Mutt send Email with String

Tags: shell, unix, csh, mutt

I am using a .csh script on my Centos 5.5 - yes:) - with Mutt (V 1.5).

Well, I can send an Email no problem like so:

```
echo "" | mutt  -s 'Subject' -i /tmp/body.txt 'test@test.com'
```

Now I want to save above parameters in a variable and then call mutt with its contents...

The variable contains the following in the end:

***-s 'Subject' -i /tmp/body.txt 'test@test.com'***

The question is not how to "extract" this string to execute the above command.

I have tried:

```
    set MailString="-s 'Subject' -i /tmp/body.txt 'test@test.com'"

    # (Tried these, don't work)
    #echo "" | mutt `echo "$MailString"`
    #echo "" | mutt `echo $MailString`
    #echo "" | mutt echo $MailString`
    #echo "" | mutt $MailString`
```

Comment: Why csh? Can you rewrite as ksh?

Comment: I am merely looking for this one line. If I do not figure it out ill just apply it directly after mutt (not as pretty but will work)

Comment: This is a common bash question (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) but I haven't used csh for over 20 years. The "csh considered harmful" essay made too much sense to ignore ;)

Answer (score 0):

**csh**

hope this will help:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set MailString="-s 'Subject' -i /tmp/body.txt test@test.com"
mutt ${MailString}
```

write MailString in `${}` and it should work for you

if you would like to have it more flexible:

you can use args for the different fields   :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set attach_file='file.txt'
set subject='My subject'
set text_file='/tmp/body.txt'

set MailString="-a ${attach_file} -s ${subject} -i ${text_file}  test@test.com"

mutt ${MailString}
```

you can push script's args to different field using `$1`,`$2`, etc...

Comment: I used echo "" | mutt ${MailString} like you said. Gives me:    Error in command line: invalid header field. Error sending message, child exited 67 (User unknown.).

Comment: ...When I copy the command directly from the console and use mutt manually it works

Comment: Why do you use the `echo` in your script?. -i will dump the file to your mail as text

Comment: If I use mutt directly (without prepending echo "" |) in the .csh file and then call that csh file from putty it's like typing "mutt" in putty -> which directly brings me into the mutt-program (interface).  my prog: //i.imgur.com/opUWKNA.png